# How to prevent form from submission?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, bootstrap-modal

I have two modals: the one is to confirm the payment if user accepts, it opens the other modal to allow uploading the receipt to be sent to the client. Now consider a situation I want to allow users to cancel the upload even after selecting the file of the receipt, by preventing the form from submitting.

Below is my code for the template and JavaScript, but the form is still submitting.

```js
let ApprovePayment = document.getElementById('uploadReceiptButton')
if (ApprovePayment) {

  CancelConfirmation = document.getElementById('CancelSubmission')
  if (CancelConfirmation) {

    CancelConfirmation.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      // Prevent the form submission            
      event.preventDefault();

    });

  }
  ApprovePayment.addEventListener('click', ApprovePaymentFunction);
}

function ApprovePaymentFunction(event) {

  event.preventDefault(); // prevent the link from opening immediately
  var receiptUploadForm = document.getElementById('receiptUploadForm')


  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: 'Confirm that the correct Receipt is sent to the Applicant',
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes!'
  }).then((result) => {

    // Remove the Cancel listener, so the form submits when "Yes" is clicked
    CancelConfirmation.removeEventListener('click');
    if (result.isConfirmed) {

      receiptUploadForm.submit();
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="modal fade" id="confirmationModal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="confirmationModalLabel" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="confirmationModalLabel">Are you sure?</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Confirm the required amount is received for this service
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#fileUploadModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="fileUploadModal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="fileUploadModalLabel" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'approve-centre-renewal-payment' query.centre_renewal.id %}" id="receiptUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="fileUploadModalLabel">Receipt</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">

            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="receipt">Upload receipt</label>
              <input type="file" id="receipt" name="receipt" class="form-control" accept="application/pdf" required>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" id="CancelSubmission">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="uploadReceiptButton">Upload</button>
          </div>

        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `CancelConfirmation = document.getElementById('CancelConfirmation')` - don't see an element with that ID in the HTML you have shown.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research .  If you get stuck, [edit] and post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @CBroe i have updated id in the script being reffered to, and thanks,

Comment: This already has `data-bs-dismiss="modal"` set, so I am guessing that Bootstrap's own event handling probably interferes with your attempt here. You should simply add `type="button"` to this button, so that it is not a submit button any more - then clicking it won't submit the form to begin with, so you don't have to try and prevent it afterwards either.

Comment: Thank you everyone, i have managed to figure out the problem and fixed it, i put an id on a wrong line